# extracting a value out of a stdClass object

Tags: php, arrays, object

My `var_dump` on the variable `$results` shows something like this

```
array (size=11)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[69]
      public 'Tables_in_database-name-here' => string 'wp_commentmeta' (length=14)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[68]
      public 'Tables_in_database-name-here' => string 'wp_comments' (length=11)
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[67]
      public 'Tables_in_database-name-here' => string 'wp_links' (length=8)

  ...

  10 => 
    object(stdClass)[59]
      public 'Tables_in_database-name-here' => string 'wp_users' (length=8)
```

I'd like to be able to extract the table names out of the above structure, and list them in a comma separated form like this;

```
 `wp_commentmeta,wp_comments,wp_links....,wp_users`
```

I got a brain freeze moment as to how to extract this data out of that structure though.

I tried quite a few options as you can follow it thru the code below - each ended uo with an error!

```
    foreach ($results as $current_item):
        /*
         * $current_item is something like this:
         * 
         * object(stdClass)[69]
            public 'Tables_in_database-name-here' => string 'wp_commentmeta' (length=14)
         */

        # echo $current_item;      
        # fires an error as "Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string"

        # echo $current_item[1]; 
        # fires an error as "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in..."

        # echo array_values($current_item); 
        # fires an error as "array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given in .."

        # echo $current_item['Tables_in_database-name-here']; 
        #fires an error as "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in "

        how do you get that darn thing? :)

    endforeach;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main problem is the property name `Tables_in_database-name-here` which can't be represented via the usual `$obj->propertyName` means. PHP lets you use a string property name via `$obj->{'invalid-variable-name-but-ok-as-a-property'}`.

I'd simply construct the string via `implode()` and `array_map()`, eg

```
$string = implode(',', array_map(function($result) {
    return $result->{'Tables_in_database-name-here'};
}, $results));
```

Demo ~ https://eval.in/172247

Regarding the property name, you can also cast `stdclass` objects to an array. For example...

```
$associativeArray = (array) $result;
// array(1) { ["Tables_in_database-name-here"] => string(14) "wp_commentmeta" }

$indexedArray = array_values($associativeArray);
// array(1) { [0] => string(14) "wp_commentmeta" }
```

Comment: thank you for your code.. I see now.. is there a way to avoid using the hardcoded 'Tables_in_database-name-here' in the code - by referring to it by a numerical index or something like that? The reason I'd like to avoid the use of that specific key is that this is supposed to be a library function...

Comment: @AverageJoe I've added some more information to my answer